# filter inside list in C# -Select based on where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a response with
`LIST<ValidationModel> validationDto;`

I want to return the `LIST<ValidationModel>` with  list of views contains where `gtype=health` only

I have done the following
`returnResult = validationDto.Where(a => a.Views.Any(i => i.gType == "health")).ToList();`
but no luck.

Can any one please help here?

```
public class ValidationModel
{
    public MetadataDto Metadata { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string PId { get; set; }
    public List<ListView> ListViews { get; set; }
}

public partial class ListView
{
    public string EType { get; set; }
    public string VName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string FType { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string GType { get; set; }
    public string Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "no luck"? Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: John, ListView is a list inside of ValidationModel .Now I want to return the validarionModel  list where Listview contains gtype=="health" only

Comment: You already said that. What is wrong with the code you have that you describe as "no luck"? Does it not compile? Throws an exception? Returns too much data? Too little? Please be explicit about the problem.

Comment: It's returning all the ListView data where gtype!="heatlh"  also .which means the query is not right

Comment: Are you saying it is returning a `List<ListView>` instead of a `List<ValidationModel>`? Impossible to tell why that might be without knowing more about where you got `validationDto` and what type it is. Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change the string comparison to ignore case,

```
i.GType.Equals(groupType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

This worked in LinqPad,

```
var list = new List<ValidationModel>
{
    new ValidationModel { ListViews = new List<View>{ new View { GType="health" } } },
    new ValidationModel { ListViews = new List<View>{ new View { GType="health" } } },
};
var groupType = "health";
list.Where(a => a.ListViews.Any(i => i.GType.Equals(groupType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).Dump();
```

Comment: But it's returning other records as well where gtype != health

Comment: @mohan, use @Quan VO's suggestion and change `Any` to `All`

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the `Any` function.

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
> condition.

You should use `All` instead

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition

```
returnResult = validationDto.Where(a => a.Views.All(i => i.GroupType == groupType)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response !but no luck.It returns 0 items where i have 18 records gtype="health"

Comment: @mohan: Are the cases the same? What's the value of `groupType`?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get confused by a complicated condition, you can extract the logic to its own method. This allows you to **test the method separately** to ensure you got the logic right.

I'm not crystal clear on your requirement but this seems about right:

```
bool HasOnlyHealth(ValidationModel model)
{
    if (model.ListViews.Count != 1) return false;
    if (model.ListViews.Single().ToUpper() != "HEALTH") return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then pass the method as your delegate to the `Where` clause.

```
returnResult = validationDto.Where(HasOnlyHealth).ToList();
```